# spring-security wrong logged user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use Spring MVC [version: 2.5] and Security[version: 2.0.4].

My problem looks like that:

> First login into my app with UserA login and Password -> OK
>
> Logout UserA, UserB is login in.
>
> UserB login + password works fine, I'm in app and UserB ROLE is on. [no access for admin session if he's no admin]
>
> HOWEVER!
>
> I use this code to get data from database, about login user:
>      `userejb.findUserByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());`
>
> and my user is not UserB but UserA...

How can i fix it? What i did wrong?

My security configuration:

```
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="pl.tzim.jlp.security.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl" />
<http auto-config='true'>
    <!-- login panel dostepny dla wszystkich chetnych!-->
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.action" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/CS/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/JS/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/grafiki/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/free/**" access="" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/teacher/**" access="ROLE_TEACHER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/all/**" access="ROLE_STUDENT, ROLE_TEACHER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/student/**" access="ROLE_STUDENT, ROLE_TEACHER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="ROLE_STUDENT, ROLE_TEACHER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_STUDENT, ROLE_TEACHER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page='/free/login.action' authentication-failure-url="/free/login.action?why=error" default-target-url="/free/index.action"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/free/login.action?why=logout"/>
    <concurrent-session-control max-sessions="99" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
</http>    
<authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService' />
```

My loginUser class and method:

```
@SessionAttributes(types = {CustomUser.class}, value = "{logedUser}")
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    public UserDAO userdao;
    public CustomUser logedUser; 
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public CustomUser loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        try {
            pl.tzim.jlp.model.user.User user = this.userdao.findUserByUsername(username);
            String password = user.getPassword();
            String role = user.getAuthority().getRolename();
            boolean enabled = true;
            logedUser = new CustomUser(user.getId(), username, password, enabled, new GrantedAuthority[]{new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role)});
            return logedUser; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomUser extends User{
    private Long id;
    public CustomUser(Long id, String username, String password, boolean isEnabled, GrantedAuthority[] authorities){
        super(username, password, isEnabled, true, true, true, authorities);
        this.setId(id);
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you set the logging level to DEBUG and examine the logs to see what is happening.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I forgot about it. 


After I take a closer look on logs i found that the error was my code. 

It was sth like: 
if(logeduser!=null){
return getuserfromdatabase(); 
}
return logeduser; 

However, logeduser after first login to app never was null.

Answer (score 0):

Why you keep the last user in this attribute?

```
public CustomUser logedUser;
```

Looks like it will be overriden with every login.
And why you put it into the **Session** when Spring Security already stored it in **SecurityContextHolder**.

As Stephen said we need the log output.